# Modify Sonar overall coverage

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm pretty new to Sonar, I'm using surefire for the metrics, and I've been just wondering how can I modify the Sonar overall coverage to increase or reduce this value to make it fail my Jenkins job.
Can someone point me in the right direction? I cannot find any documentation so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not up to date what with the jenkins integration of sonar. Earlies you could install the [build breaker plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin). Depending on your Sonarqube version this will no longer work.

Usually the thresholds for your project are not configured as parameters in the project but within sonarqube. Prior to 4.3 this was done through alerts. Nowadays it's called [Quality Gates](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates).

Actually a quite good question. I could not find anything for the [maven plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) itself to set up some thresholds.

It seems to be an [ongoing discussion](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-SonarQube-5-1-buildbreaker-plugin-for-incremental-analysis-td5034401.html).

Comment: Exactly, the Quality gates is what we use